# Interpretation of ip routes rules

Tags: docker, networking

The citation comes from: https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/networking/concepts/05-bridge-networks.md

> When we peek into the host routing table we can see the IP interfaces
>   in the global network namespace that now includes docker0. The host
>   routing table provides connectivity between docker0 and eth0 on the
>   external network, completing the path from inside the container to the
>   external network.
>
> ```
> host$ ip route default via 172.31.16.1 dev eth0
> 172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.42.1
> 172.31.16.0/20 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.31.16.102
> ```

It is written: The **host table** provides connectivity between `docker0` and `eth0`. I cannot see where in that rules the connectivity is introduced. Can you explain?